# Useless client_secret in OAuth v2

Tags: api, oauth

I wonder if client_secret is still useful in OAuth v2. Indeed, when you want to receive an access_token, you have to specify client_id & client_secret. That's seem to be the only moment where client credentials are needed. So why is there a client_secret? Isn't the client_id sufficient to authorize the client.

I thought that client_secret was inherited from OAuth v1 and used for signature but I could be wrong...

Comment: Yeah, I don't get this at all. Couldn't you use use Fiddler to get both client_id and client_secret? It seems like it is equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no OAuth expert at all but the first thing that comes to my mind is that the client_id is public. For example, on facebook, you can see the client_id of your applications in many urls.

So, if this would be the only thing to send to retrieve access tokens, I could use a stolen client_id and request access token with a fake identity.

Moreover, some api authorize you to act on the behalf of a user, and some also authorize you to act on the behalf of the oauth client itself. Again, if you use only a client_id, I could use the api method used by oauth client themselves and use a stolen client_id to get some data I should not have access to.

I think it's one of the reason of the client_secret.

Comment: So to resume, we need a client_secret because the client_id is more likely to be displayed on provider services or urls. Indeed, that makes sense now. Thank you for the answer :)